# Why a member cannot receive messages from others in a group call chat of Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I used [Create Call of Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to create a group call(audio). The connection has created successfully, but every member cannot receive any chat message posted by other members.

[(picture)The phenomenon that everyone cannot receive other's message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of0Ua.png)

Request as below:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/calls
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <Token>

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.call",
  "callbackUri": "https://myhostname.ngrok.io/callback/calling",
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig"
  },
  "source": {
    "identity": {
      "application": {
        "id": "myCallingAppId"
      }
    }
  },
  "subject": "Test Call",
  "targets": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "User_1-Id",
          "displayName": "User_1-DisplayName"
        }
      },
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "User_2-Id",
          "displayName": "User_2-Name"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "myCallingAppTenant"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#communications/calls/$entity",
    "id": "481f0c00-ffff-41cd-bbc8-7e21fb5e8b1b",
    "state": "establishing",
    "transferState": null,
    "terminationReason": null,
    "direction": "outgoing",
    "ringingTimeoutInSeconds": null,
    "subject": "Test Call",
    "callbackUri": "https://myhostname.ngrok.io/callback/calling",
    "requestedModalities": [],
    "activeModalities": [],
    "routingPolicies": [],
    "tenantId": "myCallingAppTenant",
    "myParticipantId": "59e11e38-87d0-4ae5-b3ce-051ea26aa34d",
    "mediaState": null,
    "resultInfo": null,
    "answeredBy": null,
    "chatInfo": null,
    "meetingInfo": null,
    "meetingCapability": null,
    "toneInfo": null,
    "incomingContext": null,
    "callRoutes": [],
    "source": {
        "region": null,
        "languageId": null,
        "identity": {
            "user": null,
            "device": null,
            "phone": null,
            "application": {
                "id": "myCallingAppId",
                "displayName": null
            }
        }
    },
    "targets": [
        {
            "region": null,
            "languageId": null,
            "identity": {
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "phone": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": "User_1-Id",
                    "displayName": "User_1-DisplayName"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "region": null,
            "languageId": null,
            "identity": {
                "application": null,
                "device": null,
                "phone": null,
                "user": {
                    "id": "User_2-Id",
                    "displayName": "User_2-DisplayName"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "mediaConfig": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
        "removeFromDefaultAudioGroup": null,
        "preFetchMedia": []
    }
}
```

Is any configuration missed. How to create a calling with normal message communication. Could anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: What are you getting back as a response?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur The response is added, thank you!

Comment: Enabling chat thread is not supported for creating group call. Enabling chatting in creating group call could be added (with valid chat thread id as input) but not planned yet.